# Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-cli, azure-container-service, azure-aks

Am working on Azure Kubernates where we can store Docker Images in Azure. Here am trying to check my kubectl version, then am getting

> Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex: No
>   connection could be made because the target machine actively refused
>   it.

For this I followed [MSDN:uilding Microservices with AKS and VSTS – Part 2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/azuredev/2018/04/03/building-microservices-with-aks-and-vsts-part-2/)  and [MSDOCS:Kubernetes on windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/kubernetes/getting-started-kubernetes-windows#running-a-sample-service)

So, can you please suggest me “How to resolve for this issue?”

Comment: I am getting the same issue on `kubectl cluster-info`

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I think you might missed out to configure the cluster, for that you need to run the below command in your command prompt.

```
az aks get-credentials --resource-group myResourceGroup --name myAKSCluster
```

The above CLI command creates .config file with complete cluster and nodes details in your local machine.

After that you run `kubectl get nodes` command in your command prompt, then you can get the list of nodes inside the cluster like in the below image.

[image]
For reference follow this [Deploy an Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/kubernetes-walkthrough).

Comment: I ran the `az login --scope https://management.core.windows.net//.default` and logged in to my account. Next, I executed the `az aks ...` and the `kubectl get nodes` command. However, I still get `tls: failed to verify certificate: x509` error. What am I missing?

Answer (score 54):

I am on windows 10, and for me I did not enable kubernetes on Docker Desktop.

As you can see here, there are no contexts available.

[image: docker-desktop kubernetes context]

So go to settings of docker desktop and enable it as follows.

[image: docker-desktop enable kubernetes]

Now run a command as follows.

```
kubectl config get-contexts
```

Ensure you see something like this.

[image: kubectl contexts on command line]

Also you can also try listing the nodes as follows.

```
kubectl get nodes
```

[image]

Comment: Enabling Kubernetes results with a bunch of new docker images. For example `docker/desktop-storage-provisioner:v2.0`, `registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.25.9`, `hubproxy.docker.internal:5555/docker/...`, and alike. After disabling the settings, the docker images are not deleted.

How to delete all kubernetes docker images automatically if I would like to disable it?

Comment: If you want to delete the docker images/containers that are created then follow these steps. First, delete the `docker-desktop` node by executing `kubectl drain docker-desktop --ignore-daemonsets --delete-local-data --force` and `kubectl delete node docker-dekstop` commands. Second, disable Kubernetes by unchecking the "Enable Kubernetes" option. After that, go to the "Images" plane and delete all the docker image. Docker image start with `docker/desktop...`, `hubproxy.docker....`, and `registry.k8s.io/...` name.

Answer (score 18):

If you can see that your config file is correctly configured by going to `$HOME/.kube/config` - **Linux** or `%UserProfile%/.kube/config` - **Windows** but you are still receiving the error message - try running command line as an administrator.

More information on the config file can be found here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/organize-cluster-access-kubeconfig/

Comment: For Windows 10: running command line as an administrator resolved the issue.

Comment: The first part was enough for me. The `config` file was missing completely.

Comment: This is actually the right one for me. I was running another context mini-kube

Comment: This solves the problem for me on Windows (PowerShell) - make sure the user `C:\Users\<admin-user>` has the `config` file. 
In my case I found and copied it from a non-admin user `C:\Users\<non-admin-user>\.kube\config`

Answer (score 9):

In my case, I was shuffling between `az aks k8s` cluster and local `docker-desktop`.

So every time I change the cluster context I need to restart the docker, else I get the same described error.

`Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:6443: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

[image]

PS: make sure your cluster is started as shown in this picture showing (Stop local cluster)

Comment: This error pops up for me only when I try to do a curl or HTTP requests. When I try executing `kubectl get pods` it works fine for me. Any suggestions on what can I do to make it work for HTTP requests?

Answer (score 7):

Essentially this problem occurs if your minikube or kind isn't configured. Just try to restart your minikube or kind. If that doesn't solve your problem then try to restart your hypervisor which minikube uses.

```
minikube start
```

This command solved my issue.

Answer (score 5):

For me it appeared to be due to Windows not having a HOME environment variable set.  According to the docs `kubectl` will use the config file `$(HOME)/.kube/config`. But since this variable isn't set on Window it can't locate the file.

I created a HOME variable with the same value as USERPROFILE and it started working.

Answer (score 5):

Check docker is running and you started minikube or whichever cloud kube you using.
my issue resolved after running "minikube start --driver=docker"

Answer (score 4):

I'm using Hyper-V on Local Windows and I met this error because I didn't configure minikube.

(I know the question is about Azure, not minikube. But this article is on the top for the error message. So, I've put the solution here.)

**1. enable Hyper-V.**

Type in `systeminfo` on your Terminal. If you can find the line below,

```
Hyper-V Requirements:     A hypervisor has been detected. Features required for Hyper-V will not be displayed.
```

Hyper-V works correctly.

If you can't, [enable it from settings.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/quick-start/enable-hyper-v)

**2. Create Hyper-V Network Switch**

Open Hyper-V manager. (Searching it is the fastest way.)

Next, click your PC name on the left.

Then, you can find Virtual Switch Manager menu on the right.

Click it and choose External Virtual Switch with name: "Minikube Switch"

Click apply to create it.

**3. start minikube**

Go back to terminal and type in:

```
minikube start --vm-driver hyperv --hyperv-virtual-switch "Minikube Switch"
```

For more information, [check the steps in this article](https://medium.com/@JockDaRock/minikube-on-windows-10-with-hyper-v-6ef0f4dc158c).

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same error while firing the command "kubectl get pods"

The issue has been resolved by having following steps below:

a) First find out current-context

```
kubectl config get-contexts
CURRENT   NAME      CLUSTER   AUTHINFO   NAMESPACE
```

b) if no context is set then set it manually by using

```
kubectl config set-context <Your context>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: what context should i set?

Comment: when you answer, please provide enough details, what is the significance of context ?? What should the context be set to ??

Answer (score 3):

If you're facing this error on windows, its possible that your docker instance is not running.

These are the steps I followed to replicate the above error;

1. Stopped docker and then tried to start-up an nginx-deployment. Doing this caused the mentioned error above to happen.

[image]

**How did I solve it?**

1. Check if minikube is running in my case this was not running
   [image]
2. Start minikube
   [image]
3. Retry applying your configuration above. In my case see the screenshot below

[image]

4. When you see that your deployment has been created, then all should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue after enabling kubenetes from the Docker Desktop running on Windows 10 Professional. I followed the instruction here https://www.ntweekly.com/2018/05/08/kubernetes-windows-error-unable-connect-server-dial-tcp-16445-connectex-no-connection-made-target-machine-actively-refused/ and it solved my issue. In summary,

1. I opened powershell as admin and ran [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("KUBECONFIG", $HOME + ".kube\config", [EnvironmentVariableTarget]::Machine).
2. Next I went to Docker Desktop settings and reset kubenetes. That solved it. [image]

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem even after having correct config (by running an azure cli command).

It seems that kubectl expects HOME env.variable set but it did not exist for me. There is however a solution:

If you add a KUBECONFIG environmental variable that will point to config it will start working.

Example:

```
setx KUBECONFIG %UserProfile%\.kube\config
```

When the variable is present kubectl has no troubles reading from file.

P.S. It is an alternative to setting a HOME variable as suggested in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Azure self-hosted agent doesn't have the permission to access Kubernates cluster:

```
Remove Azure self-hosted agent -  .\config.cmd Remove
configure again ( .\config.cmd) with a user have permission to access Kubernates cluster
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue in windows. 
After changing the Kubernetes running from **minikube** to **docker-desktop**, my problem was resolved.
[image]

ps: if you haven't enabled kubernetes in docker-desktop, please enable it first.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar problem:

```
> kubectl cluster-info
"To further debug and diagnose cluster problems, use 'kubectl cluster-info dump'.
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp xxx.x.x.x:8080: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

> kubectl cluster-info dump
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp xxx.0.0.x:8080: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

This setup was working fine until Docker for Desktop bought it's own copy of kubectl. There are 2 ways to overcome this situation:

1 - Quit / Stop Docker for Desktop while using the cluster

2 - Set KUBECONFIG file path

I tried both the options and they worked.

Found a good source for .kube/config, sending it over here for quick reference:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: fake-ca-file
    server: https://1.2.3.4
  name: development
- cluster:
    insecure-skip-tls-verify: true
    server: https://5.6.7.8
  name: scratch
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: development
    namespace: frontend
    user: developer
  name: dev-frontend
- context:
    cluster: development
    namespace: storage
    user: developer
  name: dev-storage
- context:
    cluster: scratch
    namespace: default
    user: experimenter
  name: exp-scratch
current-context: ""
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: developer
  user:
    client-certificate: fake-cert-file
    client-key: fake-key-file
- name: experimenter
  user:
    password: some-password
    username: exp

Reference: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/
```

Answer (score 0):

Following @ilya-chernomordik,
I've added my config path to the System Variable by doing

setx KUBECONFIG "D:\Minikube\Minikube.minikube\config"

I have changed the default Location from C: Drive to D: Drive as i have less space in C.

Now the problem is fixed.

edit: after 5 mins, the api server again stopped. It's been more than 5-6 hours i'm trying to solve this issue. I'm not sure why this problem is happening, even after adding the coreect path.

Answer (score 0):

On Rancher Desktop, make sure context is correctly choosen

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For wsl on Windows.

If your k8s cluster is running on wsl and you are getting this error from your ide on windows or windows command line, copy over your kubeconfig from wsl to your .kube folder inside C:/Users/<your_username>

and recheck.

Answer (score -1):

In my situation, I'm in windows with docker desktop in a simple scenario just for studies, but the case is:

In the docker version in 20.10 or above, it come with kubernetes installed. Then it doesn't necessary installed a cluster adm like minikube. Then, when it just need to enable kubernetes in Docker Desktop configuration. Like:

Go to Docker Desktop: **settings** > **kubernetes** > check the box inside section **Enable kubernetes** and then click in **Restart Kubernetes Cluster**

When we do this, the docker provide all needed to works Kubernetes properly.

Referenced by: [Blog](https://ict.ken.be/kubernetes-unable-to-connect-to-the-server-dial-tcp-18080-connectex-no-connection-could-be-made-because-the-target-machine-actively-refused-it)