# mobaxterm is not able to read kube config setting when using with kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, mobaxterm

I am using `MobaXterm_21.2` installed version.
When I run `kubectl version`, it's working as expected:

```
 kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"14", GitVersion:"v1.14.3", GitCommit:"5e53fd6bc17c0dec8434817e69b04a25d8ae0ff0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-06-06T01:44:30Z", G
oVersion:"go1.12.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"windows/amd64"}
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
```

But it is not able to read the `.kube/config` file or able to pickup the config file given through ENV variable `KUBECONFIG` or `--kubeconfig`. See the response below:

```
  export KUBECONFIG=/drives/path/to/config/file.config
                                                                                                                                                                                        ✔

  kubectl config view
apiVersion: v1
clusters: []
contexts: []
current-context: ""
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users: []
```

Not working either:

```
 kubectl config --kubeconfig=/drives/path/to/config/file.config  view
apiVersion: v1
clusters: []
contexts: []
current-context: ""
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users: []
```

**This is a kind of blocking issues for me. Can anyone guide me on how to make `kubectl` work in mobaxterm? Any help will be highly appreciated.**

**Edit** - like @mikolaj-s pointed. From `powershel/cmd/gitbash`, I am able to access the k8s cluster with out any problem. I have been accessing the cluster using powershell for several months now and it reads the `.kube/config` file or `KUBECONFIG` env var as expected.
I want to shift to mobaxterm for it's multi-tab feature. If there is another tool that provides multi-tab feature I might be ok with it too.

In Mobaxterm -

```
 kubectl cluster-info dump 
Unable to connect to the server: dial tcp [::1]:8080: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.

 kubectl config get-contexts --kubeconfig /path/to/config/file
CURRENT   NAME   CLUSTER   AUTHINFO   NAMESPACE
```

The kubeconfig files i am using are tested and have no issues for sure(100%) as they are working from powershell.

**Edit 2 -** Many thanks for @mikolaj-s.
With lot of hope I tried using powershell in mobaxterm as suggest by mikolaj - [mobaxterm-windows-command-prompt](https://codetryout.com/mobaxterm-windows-command-prompt/) and **it worked.**

Comment: Try giving the path in double quotes.

Comment: @confusedgenius, i tried it . But you might me saying any thing bit different. Can you put the code here .

Comment: @confusedgenius - further, in the first case it should pick the .kube/config file.. but its failing to do even that.

Comment: How did you install Kubernetes? Did you try running these commands in PowerShell? Could you check solutions from similar issues -  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50490808/unable-to-connect-to-the-server-dial-tcp-18080-connectex-no-connection-c) and from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59860987/kubectl-config-view-gives-empty-results)?

Comment: @MikolajS. - am using powershell and it work will. Please see my edit.

Comment: You can use any Windows shell in the Mobaxterm (Cmd, Powershell etc.) - check [this](https://codetryout.com/mobaxterm-windows-command-prompt/) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1418606/how-to-get-an-elevated-powershell-in-mobaxterm). Is it OK for you?

Comment: @MikolajS. - please see edit-2. Would you mind posting it as answer so i can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use PowerShell directly in the MobaXterm - steps how to configure that can be [found here](https://codetryout.com/mobaxterm-windows-command-prompt/) (instead of `CMD` choose `Powershell`):

> MobaXterm comes with various client tools such as SSH, telnet, WSL, CMD, and so on. It can well handle a Windows command line as well, here is how,

> How to open Windows command prompt using MobaXterm?
>
> - Open your MobaXterm
> - From the top menu, click on Sessions
> - From the Session settings window, click on the Shell button
> - Under the Basic Shell settings tab, select Terminal shell CMD
> - Also select a startup directory of your choice, which the CMD prompt will start it as you startup folder.
> - Now, Click the OK button to open a windows command window!

> With this, you should be able to use multiple Windows command lines in a tabbed view, or along with your other sessions.